# how the submit action works in joomla?

Tags: joomla3.4

I am new to joomla.
I have created a component using component creator. I've a form in admin side storing the details of a location, when the detail is saved I need to get the last insert id of this table to insert in another table with some extra details.

I would like to know how to get the inserted id and where the submit action goes.

Answer (score 1):

Component folder in the Administrator includes all the components we use. view.html.php file includes the action to be done.

JToolBarHelper::save('yourcontrollername.save', 'JTOOLBAR_SAVE');

The save function calls the default save event. To include your custom action, define a save function in the controller.